# Why can't I use fig.show() to plot my graph

Tags: plotly, data-visualization

I'm still not quite understand about plotly. I got this code from kaggle.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, plot
trace1 =go.Scatter(
                x = df2015['Country'],
                y = df2015['Happiness Score'],
                mode = "markers",
                name = "2015",
                marker = dict(color = 'red'),
                #line = dict(color='firebrick', width=4, dash='dot'),
                text= df2015.Country)
trace2 =go.Scatter(
                x = df2015['Country'],
                y = df2016['Happiness Score'],
                mode = "markers",
                name = "2016",
                marker = dict(color = 'green'),
                text= df2016.Country)
trace3 =go.Scatter(
                x = df2015['Country'],
                y = df2017['Happiness Score'],
                mode = "markers",
                name = "2017",
                marker = dict(color = 'blue'),
                text= df2017.Country)
trace4 =go.Scatter(
                x = df2015['Country'],
                y = df2018['Happiness Score'],
                mode = "markers",
                name = "2018",
                marker = dict(color = 'black'),
                text= df2017.Country)
trace5 =go.Scatter(
                x = df2015['Country'],
                y = df2019['Happiness Score'],
                mode = "markers",
                name = "2019",
                marker = dict(color = 'pink'),
                text= df2017.Country)

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5]
layout = dict(title = 'Happiness Rate Changing 2015 to 2019 for Top 20 Countries',
          xaxis= dict(title= 'Country',ticklen= 5,zeroline= False),
          yaxis= dict(title= 'Happiness',ticklen= 5,zeroline= False),
          hovermode="x"
         )
fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)
iplot(fig)
```

This one using iplot to show the graph. But when I tried replace iplot with fig.show() (Like suggested in https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#connected-scatterplots) I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Anyone know why it happened?

Comment: I ran your code looking for similar data. No error was generated and the graph was displayed correctly. My running version is 5.2.2. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have created dict, not the plotly Figure.

replace
`fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)`

with

`fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)`

`fig.show()`

and it should work.